# Importance of setting database type character limits

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema

I have always been taught that when creating a db that I set the database types to the max characters thats going to be in that field - e.g `int(2)`.

However as we know sometimes this can be unknown due to so many different lengths of data.

Is it really a must or can we just set to `255`.  If it is required does anyone know of a guide or a website that gives a clear list of what the character limits should be for "general" specific fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major downside of setting a size limit that's too small is that you are unable to accomodate data that you really need to store.  The easiest way to grasp this is to recall the Y2K problem.  Many systems built much earlier stored the year part of the date in two digits.  The designers probably thought their system would be discarded before it became a problem.  But in about October of 1999, managers began to worry about how many systems were going to fail come New Years.  The problems you might face are analogous, although probably smaller in scope.

There are two major downsides to setting a size limit that's much larger than what you really need.  The first is wasted computer resources.  This can result in needing more disk space, or producing more of a delay time for urgent transactions.

You also risk allowing data that should have been rejected.  Many programmers prefer putting all the data integrity checks in their apps instead of relying on the DBMS to do the same job.  There are a variety of reasons to choose either the DBMS or the apps, or both for data integrity.  But you can harm yourself if you are limited by your own ignorance of how a DBMS really works.

There is no blanket rule.  Understand your requirements, and design for your case.